# Importing Visio document in latex

Tags: graphics

I created some pdf files in Visio which includes some figures as well as text. I need to import those PDF files in Latex, what I want is to match the syntax and font of text in PDF files with syntax and font in latex. Is that possible ? and how can I proceed?

Waiting for helpful replies.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316089/how-to-export-visio-graphic-for-tex-document A similar question.
One possible solution.

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate of the linked question to me.  The old question asks about margins, this one about fonts.

Comment: @JPi Indeed.  It's the wrong duplicate.  The correct duplicate would be https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word

Comment: @HenriMenke: I don't see how that one is either.  Here, the author is simply trying to match fonts.  But yes, there are duplicates somewhere.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

you have to check what font you are using and tell us if it's a truetype or other...
LaTeX does not work with all fonts. There are different types of TeX systems to do that, like XeLaTeX.

Edit:
Ok thats the easyest way, lmodern is a package and avalable in most installations like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,6},scale=.8,pagecommand={}]{path/to/file}
\end{document}
```

Then you can include your pdf per page or all with `pages={-}`
I'm mostly glad to have the scale prepared becase visio aims to be landscape and have frames or ledgends in it. There is even a crop function in this package. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex

Here is the manual: http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf

Comment: I'm using Latin Modern.

Comment: I'm doing the same, but the font in the pdf is still the parent Times New Roman, it doesn't match with the font in Latex.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to adjust fonts in Latex or in Visio?  If you want to use the same fonts in Latex that you used in Visio then you can accomplish this easily in Lualatex or XeLatex, provided that you have these fonts installed on your system.  Just look at the documentation on how to load fonts.  See e.g. [System fonts with LaTeX? (OS X)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207771/system-fonts-with-latex-os-x)

Comment: Actually, i want to adjust in Latex. I m using Lmodern font in latex.

Comment: What font are you using in Visio?

Comment: Times new roman.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317554/change-font-to-times-new-roman-in-pdflatex

Comment: But I want to match Time new roman in pdf to Latin Modern in Latex.